# htaccess - Remove www and selectively force https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Having a difficult time finding the combination to satisfy the following 3 conditions. What Rewrite rules and conditions will accomplish the conditions? (I've already been surprised by the rules not working.)

1. www stripped from all requests
2. https for all requests to primary
3. http for all requests to ***subdomain*** (in subfolder of main site) subdomain.com

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.primary\.mobi [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^primary\.mobi [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?subdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The above do not strip www and send www.subdomain to https.

Explanations welcomed. Trying to understand the apache mod_rewrite manual page and have tried several methods without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the domain and use it in your RewriteRule. HTTP_REQUEST is not available in the substitution part, but only in RewriteCond directives.

I'm not sure, but you can try to split this into two `.htaccess` files. This one goes into the main directory

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove www. from HTTPS requests
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(primary\.mobi)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1/$0 [R,L]

# redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(primary\.mobi)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1/$0 [R,L]
```

and this is for the `.htaccess` in the subdomain folder

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove www. from HTTP requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(subdomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1/$0 [R,L]

# redirect HTTPS requests to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(subdomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1/$0 [R,L]
```

Test your rules *without* 301, because the browser caches 301 results and makes testing much harder. Add `R=301` not until you're satisfied with the rules.

In [Canonical Hostnames](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost) are some alternatives described, especially the first one, using virtual hosts, looks promising

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.primary.mobi
    Redirect / https://primary.mobi/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName primary.mobi
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.subdomain.com
    Redirect / http://subdomain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't know, if this is feasible for you, but you might try.

Comment: Danke Olaf. That works for primary. For subdomain.com, a request for www.subdomain.com results in http://subdomain.comsubdomain.com and dns failure. I tried to remove each back-reference individually, and still no success. Did you notice this is a subdomain, in folder subdomain. I think the RewriteBase / is having an affect on this.

Comment: @DavidC Do you have the primary in the main directory and subdomain in a subdirectory `subdomain.com`? Is subdomain configured as a virtual host?

Comment: @DavidC Do you have the `RewriteRule`s in the server/virtual host configuration or are they in `.htaccess` files?

Comment: primary.mobi is in document root. subdomain.com is in a subdirectory named `/subdomain`. I don't have access to http-vhosts.conf file, because this is on a hosted server. It is set-up through cPanel as a 'subdomain' of the primary site. It's document root is set to be `public_html/subdomain`. 2nd question: location of these rules is htaccess.

Comment: @OlafDietsche What does `$0` refer to? I've never seen that before in mod_rewrite context.

Comment: @DavidC `$0` is the matched string of the rewrite rule, `$1, $2, ...` refer to subgroups. Same for `%0, %1, ...` for matches in the last rewrite condition. There's a nice graphic about "Regex Back-Reference Availability" at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: @DavidC Does splitting the rewrite rules into two .htaccess files work for you?

Comment: @Perleone Sorry, missed your name. See my answer to David.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Do you mean removing subdomain.com from the document root htaccess and adding it to /subdomain/.htaccess ?

Comment: @DavidC Yes, it's just a try.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Danke, never noticed the 0 before, only 1-9. "$0 provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern." I should RTFM more often.

Comment: Olaf, I can't tell you separate htaccess is working. Requesting (www.)?primary.mobi/anything.php results in https://primary.mobianything.php. Only (www.)?primary.mobi results in the index page.

Comment: @DavidC Ok, then you need a slash in between `%1/$0`, updated answer.

Comment: I must slow down!! (I'm starting to be cross-eyed) The slash is missing from `primary.mobianything.php`, instead of `subdomain.com`

Comment: @DavidC Yes, I modified the answer already. I added a slash between `%1` and `$0`. I'm sorry, this is sort of a blind flight for me. I'm just experimenting right now.

Comment: @DavidC Please see updated answer. I think, I forgot to remove www. with https for the primary domain. Please verify.

Comment: @OlafDietsche  Good catch. Thank you for correcting your answer. 'Splitting' the htaccess into 2 is the best way to go. I also removed the trailing $ in the remove RewriteCond to match a www.primary.mobi request.